# Remove Roll over for preview from image in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, php

When i view product images in admin then i have to roll over on image  thumbnail to see the image i want to get it removed and show images directly  so that i don't have to roll over the image

Comment: It's default feature provided by Magento. U have to customize code

Answer (score 1):

Did the same thing on our Magento site, this is how i accomplished it.

file to modify:

```
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
```

go-to (first instance of) [Line:70]:

```
<td class="cell-image">
```

find:

```
<div class="place-holder" onmouseover="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.loadImage('__file__')"><span><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Roll Over for preview') ?></span></div>
```

replace with:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog'); ?>/media/catalog/product__file__" width="100" alt="" />
```

Comment: You're a genius!